# an app or a batch file script to remove special characters from text

Tags: windows, batch-file

I love this online tool http://textmechanic.co/ but it lacks another important feature which is to delete special characters such as %, %, [, ), *, ?, ', etc.. except for _, -, and . from a large quantity of text.

I am looking for an online tool or a small windows utility or a batch script that can do this.

Answer (score 2):

I think `sed` is the easiest choice here. You can download it for Windows [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) Furthermore, nearly every text editor should allow that (but most won't cope with files in the multi-GiB range well).

With `sed` you'd probably want something like this:

```
sed "s/[^a-zA-Z0-9_.-]//g" file.txt
```

Likewise, if you have a semi-recent Windows (i.e. Windows 7), then PowerShell comes preinstalled with it. The following one-liner will do that for you:

```
Get-Content file.txt | foreach { $_ -replace '[^\w\d_.-]' } | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 file.new.txt
```

This can easily adapted to multiple files as well. It could be that you also can output into the original file again, since I think `Get-Content` yields an array, not an enumerator (i.e. this pipeline cannot operate on the file as you read it). Similar problem due to that with very large files, though.

Comment: i am sorry but i am a complete noob when it comes to this. how do i use this one liner code you wrote with sed?

Comment: @techdaemon: You don't. That was PowerShell, just as I wrote. I added a `sed` example, though, which works along the same lines (but only works for ASCII text, I think). I just don't have `sed` around, usually, so I couldn't provide an example right away.

Comment: i am not really knowledgeable about your techspeak. can you put it in layman's term? i mean the average computer user. i just need to get rid of a lot of special characters in a text file. just delete, not replace but excluding period, underscore and dash. thanks in advance if you can help me.

Comment: @techdaemon: If you replace something by nothing you effectively delete it. That's why many environments just have a powerful replace operation and no explicit delete. Your question was vague enough that I thought you would know enough to make a solution work for you but honestly, since I don't know exactly what you need (except to delete such characters from text) I cannot give you a full solution you just need to apply. Also asking for others to do your work completely is a bit frowned upon here.

Comment: so how so i use the sed code or powershell code you wrote? where do i type it? i'm using windows and not unix or linux.

Comment: Well, for `sed` open a command window and just paste it and append `> file.new.txt` or whereever you want the results. For the PowerShell one open PowerShell and just paste the code. Adapt the file names accordingly first, though. And you might want to navigate to the directory where your file resides first (using `cd`).

Answer (score 1):

You can do regex with any tool/language that supports it. Here's a [Ruby for Windows](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) command

```
C:\work>ruby -ne 'print $_.gsub(/[%)?\[\]*]/,"")' file
```